# Reading from XML based on multiple attributes

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010

I have an XML in the following format:

```
<Accounts>
  <Account ID="1"   City="Bangalore" Amount="2827561.95" /> 
  <Account ID="225" City="New York"  Amount="12312.00" /> 
  <Account ID="236" City="London"    Amount="457656.00" /> 
  <Account ID="225" City="London"    Amount="23462.40" /> 
  <Account ID="236" City="Bangalore" Amount="2345345.00" /> 
</Accounts>
```

Here, what makes an account unique is the combination of attributes `ID` and `City`.

How do I read the `Amount` uniquely? How do I read amount for a combination of `ID` and `City` attributes?

For example, I need to get the `Amount` for the account with `ID=225` and `City=London`. If I use code like

```
Node.GetAttribute('ID')=225
```

it always gives me the first node with ID=225

Thanking you.

Comment: How do you use `Node.GetAttribute('ID')=225`? Do you use it in a loop or ...?

Comment: Yes..I was using that inside a loop. Something like...   Node:=rootNode.ChildNodes.FindNode(‘Accounts’);
for i := 0 to Node.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do begin
   childnode:= Node.ChildNodes[i];
   if Node.HasAttribute('ID') then
   amount:=Node.GetAttribute('ID');
…..

Comment: Then you could just add a second condition to your if statement that compares the content of `City`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with XPath, using this sentence `./Accounts/Account[@ID="225"][@City="London"]` to locate the node.

Try this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  MSXML,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

Const
 XmlStr =
' <Accounts>'+
'  <Account ID ="1"   City="Bangalore" Amount="2827561.95"/>'+
'  <Account ID="225" City="New York"  Amount="12312.00"/>'+
'  <Account ID="236" City="London"    Amount="457656.00"/>'+
'  <Account ID="225" City="London"    Amount="23462.40"/>'+
'  <Account ID="236" City="Bangalore" Amount="2345345.00"/>'+
'</Accounts>';

procedure Test;
Var
  XMLDOMDocument  : IXMLDOMDocument;
  XMLDOMNode      : IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  XMLDOMDocument:=CoDOMDocument.Create;
  XMLDOMDocument.loadXML(XmlStr);
  XMLDOMNode := XMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode(Format('./Accounts/Account[@ID="%s"][@City="%s"]', ['225', 'London']));
  if XMLDOMNode<>nil then
    Writeln(Format('Amount %s',[String(XMLDOMNode.attributes.getNamedItem('Amount').Text)]));
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Test;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: +1. You can also use XPath: `/Accounts/Account[@ID="%s" and @City="%s"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAmount(Id, City: string): string;
begin
  Result := ''
  aNode := xmldocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['Accounts'];
  for i := 0 to ChildNodes.Count do 
    with aNode.Nodes[i] do
      if (Attributes['ID'] = Id) and (Attributes['City'] = City) then 
      begin
        Result:= Attributes['Amount'];
        Break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```